# Add namespace to T-SQL query using XML FOR

Tags: sql, xml, namespaces, sql-server-2012

I have to include the XML namespace for a custom fields.

Sample Query

```
SELECT field1 as '@attr1'
FROM table1
FOR XML PATH ('node')
```

What I am receiving so far is:

```
<node attr1="value" />
```

what I want to achieve is this, plain and simple, no xmlns decalrations.

```
<myname:node attr1="value">
```

How can this be achieved?

SQL Server 2012?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the XML namespace in your query, and reference it - something like this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('myname' AS ns)
SELECT field as '@attr1'
FROM table1
FOR XML PATH ('ns:node')
```

Then you'll get an output something like this:

```
<ns:node xmlns:ns="myname" attr1="value" />
```

Comment: That helps but I need to eliminate xmlns:ns="myname" as part of the attribute. My XSD son't support that.